# System.Security.Permission Error on Create Forder Method

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I heve built a Plugin, but for my needs, I have to write all logs on a text file. 
But on debug mode, I notice that  when thecode step through the following snippet

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(_filePath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(_filePath);
            }
```

it returns me this exception :

> 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

On filesystem, "everyone" is  granted  on read/write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are deploy your plugin in sandbox mode, and in this mode you have restrictions, take a [look](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx).
If you aren't using crm online try deploy in another mode.

Comment: De nada :D sempre as ordens